# An error occurred submitting the answer

Tags: support, bug, answers

I am trying to post an answer to [my own question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17097/check-if-a-user-account-was-activated-by-administrator), but I am getting an error message when I try to submit it.

The error message is: `An error occurred submitting the answer.`, which is not a very helpful message.

In the meanwhile I've posted the most relevant bits of the answer as comments against the question, but I would like to post the full answer if possible.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

It must have been a temporary glitch -- I came back later and tried again and it worked just fine.

Nothing to see here, move along please.